# Systemd SSH tunnel service failing while command works in command line

Tags: ssh, systemd, ssh-tunnel

I've been trying to setup a SSH reverse tunnel Systemd service for automatically exposing my non-public IP computer to the internet for SSHing. I have two different services, one pointing to my own server (another computer with public IP) which works fine, and one trying to use [serveo.net](https://serveo.net) (a free service of TCP tunnelling via ssh client). My service works fine for my own server but fails for Serveo.

My service definition is as follow:

```
[Unit]
Description=Setup a remote tunnel to serveo.net
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
User=ssh-tunnel
Group=ssh-tunnel
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh -T -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -i /var/lib/ssh-tunnel/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -R myalias:58227:localhost:22 serveo.net
Restart=always
RestartSec=60

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When executing the same command in the terminal, it works correctly:

```
sudo -u ssh-tunnel -g ssh-tunnel /usr/bin/ssh -T -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -i /var/lib/ssh-tunnel/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -R myalias:58227:localhost:22 serveo.net
```

The only difference of behaviour I can see between my own server and Serveo is that Serveo has a sort of interactive command interface.

Has anyone have a similar issue with Systemd services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serveo needs an interactive shell. You want to add

[Service]
StandardInput=tty-force

to force the use of a shell that works with the serveo configuration